# Как текстовый файл сохранить в строке?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь получить из текстового файла строку, в консоль выводится как надо, но сохранить не могу, как можно ее сохранить? (использую фреймворк  vue js )

```
uploadString( e ) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
        this.textToChange=reader.result
      };

      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
```

Comment: Уже были мысли значение reader.result закидывать в session storage и от туда потом выгружать это значение, искав в интернете  так и не нашел нормальное решение на данный вопрос, в  основном все только что и делают это выводят консоль лог

Comment: закройте пожалуйста вопрос, если вас устроил ответ

Answer (score 3):

У вас потерян контекст. Посмотрите что выводит this в обработчике onload

пример для test.txt

```js
const Hello = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="file" @input="uploadString"/> 
      <div v-html="msg"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello!'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveText (e) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget, e.target);
      this.msg = e.target.result
    },
    uploadString( e ) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this.saveText;
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Hello
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <hello></hello>
</div>
```

Comment: Я все равно не понял почему нельзя 
reader.onload = function() {this.textToChange=reader.result};

Comment: @Sasha потому что метод onload принадлежит к reader'у и его this это не this компонента Vue. 
https://learn.javascript.ru/bind

Comment: @Sasha 
uploadString( e ) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // reader.onload = this.saveText;
      var self = this;
      reader.onload = function() {
        console.log('this', this, self);
        this.msg = e.target.result
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    },